# tfs build can't find resx files

Tags: continuous-integration, resx, automated-deployment

I am trying to use automated builds and deployments to our test IIS web server, however, as of recently, for some reason, the builds are failing with reasons for:

```
Cannot find Errors.resx
```

Errors.resx is a file within the project, and it's checked in. Even the Publish option from VS2010 works fine.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to that, I think I ended up manually patching a value in a resource file in notepad++ 
see [msdn link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554759/error-in-control-resx-file-when-adding-imagelist)

Comment: Thanks for the link - but I don't think it fully applies here - we can compile fine, it's ONLY the TFS CI build that fails.

Also we're only using strings not an image list.